# making NmApi (Network Monitor API) example in rust. Compilation successful and the process executes without error but no capture file appears

Tags: c++, windows, rust

I'm trying to use the functionality of Network Monitor 3.4 in my rust executable: In order to do so I've added the following files in following places:

`NmApi.lib` in `target\\debug\\deps`

`NMAPI.dll` in `target\\debug`

then I've created some binding based on the in-app documentation like so:

```rust
// NMAPI module
use crate::shared::types::*;

#[link(name="NmApi")]
extern "system" {

    pub fn NmCreateCaptureFile(pFileName: LPCWSTR, ulSize: ULONG, ulFlags: ULONG, phCaptureFile: PHANDLE, pulReturnSize: PULONG) -> ULONG;
    pub fn NmOpenCaptureEngine(pCaptureEngine: PHANDLE) -> ULONG;
    pub fn NmConfigAdapter(hCaptureEngine: HANDLE, ulIndex: ULONG, CallbackFunction: NM_FRAME_CALLBACK,
                           pCallerContext: LPVOID, CaptureCallbackExitMode: NmCaptureCallbackExitMode) -> ULONG;

    pub fn NmStopCapture(pCaptureEngine: HANDLE, adapterInedx: ULONG);

    pub fn NmCloseHandle(objectHandle: HANDLE);
    pub fn NmAddFrame(hCaptureFile: HANDLE, hFrame: HANDLE) -> ULONG;
    pub fn NmStartCapture(hCaptureEngine: HANDLE, ulAdapterIndex: ULONG, CaptureMode: NmAdapterCaptureMode) -> ULONG;

}
```

```rust
// types module
pub type DWORD = u32;
pub type CHAR = u8;
pub type LONG = i32;
pub type ULONG = u32;
pub type PULONG = *mut ULONG;
pub type VOID = c_void;
pub type LPVOID = *mut VOID;
pub type LPCWSTR = *mut u16;
pub type HANDLE = *mut c_void;
pub type PHANDLE = *mut HANDLE;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
#[repr(u32)]
pub enum BOOL {
    TRUE = 1,
    FALSE = 0,
}

impl BOOL {
    const TRUE_LITERAL: &'static str = "true";
    const FALSE_LITERAL: &'static str = "false";

}

impl Debug for BOOL {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct(&format!("BOOL {}",if *self == Self::TRUE {Self::TRUE_LITERAL} else {Self::FALSE_LITERAL}))
            .finish()
    }
}


pub type NM_FRAME_CALLBACK = Option<unsafe extern "system" fn ( _: HANDLE, _: ULONG, _:  LPVOID, _: HANDLE)>;

#[repr(u32)]
pub enum NmCaptureCallbackExitMode {
    DiscardRemainFrames = 1,
    ReturnRemainFrames = 2,
}

#[repr(u32)]
pub enum NmAdapterCaptureMode {
    NmLocalOnly = 0,
    NmPromiscuous = 1,
}
```

afterwards I attempted to replicate the example below (from in in-app documentation)

```cpp
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "ntddndis.h"
#include "NMApi.h"

void __stdcall 
MyFrameIndication(HANDLE hCapEng, ULONG ulAdaptIdx, PVOID pContext, HANDLE hRawFrame)
{
    HANDLE capFile = (HANDLE)pContext;
    NmAddFrame(capFile, hRawFrame);
}

int __cdecl wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    ULONG ret;
    ULONG adapterIndex = 0;

    if(2 == argc)
        adapterIndex = _wtol(argv[1]);

    // Open a capture file for saving frames.
    HANDLE myCapFile;
    ULONG CapSize;
    ret = NmCreateCaptureFile(L"20sec.cap", 20000000, NmCaptureFileWrapAround, &myCapFile, &CapSize);
    if(ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error opening capture file, 0x%X\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }

    // Open the capture engine.
    HANDLE myCaptureEngine;
    ret = NmOpenCaptureEngine(&myCaptureEngine);
    if(ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error opening capture engine, 0x%X\n", ret);
        NmCloseHandle(myCapFile);
        return ret;
    }

    //Configure the adapter.
    ret = NmConfigAdapter(myCaptureEngine, adapterIndex, MyFrameIndication, myCapFile);
    if(ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error configuration adapter, 0x%X\n", ret);
        NmCloseHandle(myCaptureEngine);
        NmCloseHandle(myCapFile);
        return ret;
    }

    //Start capturing frames.
    wprintf(L"Capturing for 20 seconds\n");
    NmStartCapture(myCaptureEngine, adapterIndex, NmLocalOnly);

    Sleep(20000);

    wprintf(L"Stopping capture\n");
    NmStopCapture(myCaptureEngine, adapterIndex);

    NmCloseHandle(myCaptureEngine);
    NmCloseHandle(myCapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

with such implimentation:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "system" fn _MyFrameIndication(hCaptureEngine: HANDLE, adapterIndex: ULONG, pContext:  LPVOID, hRawFrame: HANDLE) {
    let hCapFile: HANDLE = pContext as HANDLE;
    let ret = unsafe { NmAddFrame(hCapFile, hRawFrame) };
    println!("capturing frame: got code {}",ret);
}

pub const MyFrameIndication: NM_FRAME_CALLBACK = Some(_MyFrameIndication);


fn main () {


    let mut myCapFile: HANDLE = unsafe { zeroed() };
    let mut CapSize: ULONG = unsafe { zeroed() };
    let mut pname: Vec<u16> = OsStr::new("20sec.cap").encode_wide().chain(once(0)).collect();
    unsafe {
        println!("opening capture file: code is {}",NmCreateCaptureFile(pname.as_mut_ptr(),
                                       2000, 0,
                                       &mut myCapFile as PHANDLE,
                                       &mut CapSize));
    };


    let mut myCaptureEngine: HANDLE = unsafe { zeroed() };
    let ret = unsafe { NmOpenCaptureEngine(&mut myCaptureEngine) };
    println!("acquiring capture engine: code is {}", ret);

    let ret = unsafe { NmConfigAdapter(myCaptureEngine,
                                   0, MyFrameIndication,
                                   myCapFile,
                                   NmCaptureCallbackExitMode::DiscardRemainFrames) };

    println!("configuring adapter: code is {}", ret);

    let ret = unsafe {NmStartCapture(myCaptureEngine, 0, NmAdapterCaptureMode::NmLocalOnly)};
    println!("starting capture: code is {}",ret);


    let before = SystemTime::now();

    while (SystemTime::now().duration_since(before).unwrap().as_secs() < 25) {

    }

    println!("stopping capture");
    unsafe {
        NmStopCapture(myCaptureEngine, 0)
    };


    println!("releasing handles");
    unsafe {
        NmCloseHandle(myCaptureEngine);
        NmCloseHandle(myCapFile);
    }
}
```

Afterwards I built the binary without any error, and launched it:
the console window appeared and the output of all codes was 0 which is the value of `ERROR_SUCCESS` implying that the functions were called correctly.

However no file appeared anywhere in the working directory.
Furthermore - nothing was printed from within the callback function.

Can anyone help me with this? was on it for some time and not even sure how to debug it.

P.S. I tried placing the .lib and .dll files in the cwd of resulting exe as well - didn't change anything.

**Update:**

I've tried creating new project and included the following config file in .cargo subdirectory:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
rustc-link-lib = {name="NmApi"}
rustc-link-search = {path="C:\\Users\\grass\\Desktop\\codes\\Rust\\cpp_xport\\res"}
```

where the target if my default. Didn't change anything sadly

Answer (score 1):

So after some time thinking and some help from rust discord community figured it out, and hopefully it'll save time for somebody else. The issue was that since the network interface 0 was an Ethernet interface it wasn't active, and the filename argument suppose to be a path actually. So switching the file name to absolute path and using the index of my Wi-Fi interface (basically counted them in the output of ipconfig \all from zero) resulted in making a capture file.